# Angular getting value of selected author in form

Tags: html, angular, typescript, angular-material, angular-material-table

I am using `MatDialog` and `UntypedFormGroup`. So from bookcomponent I am either adding new book or editing existing one. I am using same form to edit as well as add new book. For this particular form I am getting authors as observable for firestore and using in the `mat-select` and storing id of the author in book document like code below

```
  <mat-form-field appearance="fill" *ngIf="author$ | async as authors">
    <mat-label>Choose Author</mat-label>
    <mat-select formControlName="authorId">
      <mat-option *ngFor="let author of authors" [value]="author.id">
        {{author.name}}
      </mat-option>
    </mat-select>
  </mat-form-field>
```

This is working wonderfully in editing and adding new data.

**Edit:** I want to get selected `{{author.name}}` with `{{author.id}}` from above code. Sorry I question was ambiguous.

I am using `mat-table` in booklistcomponent and I want to have a column named author. I already share certain data from parent to children i.e `bookcomponent<>booklistcomponent<>bookformcomponent` by using `@input()` `emitter()` and `MatDialog`.
I tried using `ngModel` but it is not providing desired result. Is their any way I can use my existing code but also can get `author.name` value as well  without any major change in editing or adding new book code. I am stuck on this one for days now please help. Thanks in advance

Comment: Do you want to pass down `authors` from `bookComponent` to `bookListComponent`?

Comment: Hey skouch2022, sorry for the delay i edited the question. I an expecting to get both id and name for selected author, keeping in mind to bind this form two way i.e. add and edit on the same form.

Comment: Could you please include code for your `bookComponent` and `bookListComponent`? You mentioned you tried but it didn't work. You should show what you have tried.